# How to update Many-to-Many relationship ? ( No Duplicates + Remove all non-matching previous records)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

how do I update a `many-to-many` relationship in `sequelizer` so there won be duplicates?

I got a relationship like this:

```
db.contacts.belongsToMany(db.labels, {
    through: db.contactlabel,
    foreignKey: "contact_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.labels.belongsToMany(db.contacts, {
    through: db.contactlabel,
    foreignKey: "label_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});
```

say I need to update the `join table` where `contact_id = 1` and `labels` = `[1, 2, 3]`, I only want to keep these rows:

```
[{
  contact_id: 1,
  label_id: 1
 },
 {
  contact_id: 1,
  label_id: 2
 },
 {
  contact_id: 1,
  label_id: 3
 }]
```

After the update query, I only want these 3x rows to remain in the `joint table` where `contact_id = 1`, other prev rows where `contact_id = 1` and `labels` NOT in `[1, 2, 3]` will be removed

if the combo of `contact_id` and `label_id` existed ( `contact_id = 1` and `labels` IN `[1, 2, 3]` )

then the row(s) will remain, and if any of them does not exist new rows will be created

I know how to do this in `laravel`, but I do not know how to do the same in `sequelize`, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you define it right, there will be a method `setLabels` on contact instance and vice versa.

```
const contact = await Contact.findByPk(1);
await contact.setLabels([1, 2, 3]);
```

These methods are generated automatically by Sequelize, follow the convention on  https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#foobelongstomanybar--through-baz-

Comment: HI, if I use this: `await contact.setLabels([1, 2, 3]);` will the prev records be purged and only these 3x be added?

Comment: Yes, they will. It also have another method `addLabels` that will not affect other records